# How to do hypothesis testing on two samples with multiple attributes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, t-test

Example:

Given two groups of people (considerably large, and sampled independently and randomly), with the following individual attributes:

- Age
- Height
- Weight
- Education

How to test if the two groups are drawn from the same population?

For example, consider the following proposal:

Null hypothesis: the two groups are from the same population. Add a label `group_id = {0, 1}` as the response variable, perform a logistic regression `group_id ~ Age + Height + Weight + Education`. If any of the regression coefficient is significant, then reject the null hypothesis.

Would this be correct? What if more indepedent variables are added to the regression, e.g. `log(height)`, `Height/Weight`, etc.?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "population"?

Comment: The population is the underlying pool of people from which the two groups were drawn. For instance a country like USA.

Comment: I think you are looking for a MANOVA then, unless you have data on the original population? it should be something like `manova(cbind(Age, Height, Weight, Education)~group_id`)